# Image drawing in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a game in XNA, but since I have people with different operating systems, I'd like to make the mapeditor in Qt. I have C++ knowledge, I'm new to Qt though.

I'm looking for something to draw images, or rather parts of them, in an area of my application.
Something like spriteBatch.Draw, maybe. Important would be that I can define a source rectangle of the picture and a destination rectangle.

Since I'm new to Qt, detailed explanations or links to tutorials would be really appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to do this, check the [Qt Paint System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/paintsystem.html) documentation, or the  [Qt GraphicsView Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/graphicsview.html).

The  [Qt Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/all-examples.html) pages have lots of well documented samples.

Also check out the documentation of the `QPainter` and `QImage` classes.